# Angular + Node + MySQL : Reporting + Forms + Authentication

Tags: mysql, node.js, reporting, angularjs, forms

I am trying to make an in-house simple solution with Node/Angular/MySQL stack where the users are expected to enter data through 4-5 different type of forms, the entered data needs to be reported on a simple web interface (export to PDFs/EXCEL/CSV is preferable but not compulsory) with the relevant authentication levels. Another preferable feature would be allowing the users to make custom reports or at least use filters especially dates. I am using this tool as a starting point to make a much more complex one.

Would someone be able to recommend any packages for this? something like Jasper in this environment. In order of priority Reporting-> Forms -> Authentication ->Reports with filters-> Custom reports -> Custom Forms -> Export functionality . Please suggest the most easy to manage packages.

Comment: Welcome aboard. Do you want a free solution? If so, use the [tag:gratis] tag. Otherwise, please state a budget.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try [Stimulsoft Reports.JS](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/downloads/reports-js). The product specifically designed for Angular and Node. Samples of using the tool can be found in the [Samples section](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/samples/js) of the Stimulsoft website.

The product supports for Node.js, Angular, and MySQL as well. The product has the HTML5 designer and viewer to show reports in web. Also, your reports can be exported to PDF, Excel, CSV formats.

I work at Stimulsoft.

Comment: Looks good, and I upvoed because the OP did not state a budget. ***BUT***, others should be aware that it costs from US $700 to $14k for a license

Comment: Andrew, please address each of the requirements of the asker.

Comment: Useful for very simple reports, but its numerous bugs quickly become annoying at more complex reports.